# How to create a DataTable with a single row and single key-value pair in that row.

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

For a test I'm trying to write, all I need is a `DataTable` with `1` row with `["foo"] = 2314` so that I reach the body of the loop

```
foreach(DataRow row in mockDataTable.Rows)
{
     // ... 
     int val = (int)row["foo"];
     // ... 
}
```

inside a method that my test is testing.

However I can't figure out how to do this through the documentation on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try this :             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "foo", 2314 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("foo", typeof (int));
var row = dt.NewRow();
row["foo"] = 1234;
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Please include some context/explanation for this code as that makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory I think.